# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, angular, router, rxjs5, ngrx

I am using **ngrx/router**.

When I open `http://localhost/set-new-password/abc`, the `RouteParams` works well. I can get the string `token` I want.

```
const landingRouter: Routes = [
  { path: '/set-new-password/:token', component: SetNewPasswordComponent },
];

export class SetNewPasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  token: string = '';

  constructor(private _routeParams$: RouteParams) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this._routeParams$
      .pluck('token')
      .subscribe(token => {
        console.log(typeof token); // Console: "string"
        console.log(token);        // Console: "abc"
        this.token = token;        // Terminal: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      });
  }
}
```

However, I got this warning in my terminal:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I know I can use `this.token = String(token);` to get rid of it.

But why does this warning show? Can someone explain a little bit for me?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get help from @brandonroberts to @MikeRyan52's original answer, and thanks!

> Two reasons why this won't work:
>
> 1. We don't actually know the shape of the params object until runtime,
>      so there's not a good type to describe it
> 2. pluck('id') can't be well typed anyways since the string selector
>      isn't known
>
> Solution would be to explicitly type pluck():
>
> ```
> params$.pluck<string>('id')
> ```

So my situation is changing to:

```
this._routeParams$
  .pluck<string>('token')
  .subscribe(token => this.token = token);
```